# i want to prove the chain rule formula for the partial derivatives..but i can't here the detailed qn is given in below..

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

let $k(x,y)=f(g(x,y),h(x,y))$ so $h$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. Now if we let $u=g(x,y)$ and $v=h(x,y)$ then

$$\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial k}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial k}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$

If $f,g$ and $h$ had partial derivatrive wrt $x$ at $(x,y)$ and $f$ has partial derivative wrt to both $u$ and $v$ at $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$ respectively then it the formula happens.. i tried from the defn of partial derivative but there i am unable to do..plz help me out how to rigorously prove this ..

Comment: plz someone response??

Comment: @Plasma Stark plz help this one....

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy sir plz help this one....

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos plz help this one